# How to fix dry wall side of newly fitted tiles shower wall?

Tags: shower, leak, tiling

[image][image]I have had a brand new shower put in, the tiling is shown, however after about 1 month we noticed a small amount of water passing though to the dry wall. The below is now 9 months later.

The contractor does not know what is causing the problem.

The tiles and grouting used I assume are waterproof.

I would really appreciate your thoughts!

[image]

[image: Shower Tiles]

Comment: Is that on the side with the faucet and mixer?

Comment: No, the shower is on the left wall in the bath photo, that wall has no pipes, the water just hits there.

Comment: Grout is not water proof even when sealed. The membrane behind is supposed to divert the water to the drain but it has apparently failed in some way. Now when you say "not contactable" you mean he won't return calls?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm seeing the but either way it's your contractor's problem. If the membrane was installed improperly or failed he should stand by his work and make it right. If it has no membrane, it's not up to code and you've got him in a very awkward position. Being busy is not an excuse.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18868/discussion-on-question-by-luke-sewell-how-to-fix-dry-wall-side-of-newly-fitted-t).

Answer (score 5):

If you're seeing that water on the drywall on the *other side* of the wall opposite where the tile is then your shower was not installed with a proper membrane. You need a waterproof memberane and a suitable substrate for the shower.

This would be something like kerdi and/or a tile backerboard painted with redgard. You **cannot** use drywall to back it, nor can you use "green board" in most states. You need a cement board and/or a waterproof membrane.

Demolish and replace the shower ASAP. The more you allow water to penetrate that wall the bigger and bigger your problem will become. Mold **will** follow. You cannot correct this problem without removing the tile and, likely, removing the wallboard material in the shower.

Your contractor installed it improperly and he should replace it. Check the rules with the contractor's board in your county. You are likely required to allow the contractor to correct it. You can't just have somebody else do it and bill the contractor.

If you hired a licensed and bonded contractor, the building inspector can pull his bond until the work is corrected. If you hired a craigslist handyman you may be screwed.

Answer (score 2):

This will not solve your issue, but I would strongly suggest to stop using that shower if you can, and open the drywall where you see the leak. For two reasons:

- It'll help you **see** where the water is coming from.
- It will help dry out the wall and help prevent or slow down molding.

That part of the drywall is no longer needed anyways because you'll have to remove it to repair your wall.